# (Python 3.9) Calling Objects created using a loop

Tags: python, object

I am new to Python, and I am working on a Tic Tac Toe game coded using OOP. After completing the tile, however, I cannot figure out how to determine the winner (or draw). Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root =tk.Tk()
root.title('Tic Tac Toe')
player = 'cross'

class Tile():
    def __init__(self):
        self.tile = tk.Button(
            root,
            font = ('Arial', 35),
            width=3,
            command = self.write
        )

    def write(self):
        global player
        if player == 'cross':
            self.tile.config(text = 'X', state = tk.DISABLED)
            player = 'circle'
        elif player == 'circle':
            self.tile.config(text = 'O', state = tk.DISABLED)
            player = 'cross'
        else:
            print('wrong var')
    def grid(self, row, column):
        self.tile.grid(row=row, column=column)


for row in range(0,3):
    for column in range(0,3):
        Tile().grid(row, column)

root.mainloop()
```

I wonder if I can assign a name to each of the tile objects, so that I can call them later and get the button text of each of them, hence compare them with the win conditions.

Comment: You need to apply simple logic here. Check for every possible win and loose situations. If no one wins and the board is full consider it draw.

Comment: I believe that this is the common solution to a tic tac toe program. But what if the game is more complicated? Say a tic tac toe played on a 5x5 board instead of a 3x3 board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your setup to

```
tiles = []
for row in range(0,3):
    tiles.append([])
    for column in range(0,3):
        tiles[-1].append(Tile())
        tiles[-1][-1].grid(row, column)
```

you can access your tiles as tiles[row][column] at the end and get the text to compare against the win conditions.